# Searching for a phrase in text file then displaying that line

Tags: c#, asp.net, search, for-loop

im trying to make a code that searches through a textfile for a certain phrase and then  populates a textbox with the line if a phrase occurs in that. There are no errors with this code, but it doesn't work at all. Anyone know what is wrong? I'm not too sure if what i'm doing is remotely correct.

```
  {
    tuitDisplayTextBox.Text = "";
    string[] tuitFilePath = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~") +"/App_Data/tuitterMessages.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < tuitFilePath.Length; i++)
    {
        if (tuitFilePath[i].Contains(searchTextBox.Text))
        {
            tuitDisplayTextBox.Text += tuitFilePath[i];
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing it just puts the last line with that phrase in it, am I right? I'll post a LINQ solution that should work.

Comment: the code doesn't result something ?

Comment: code doesnt result anything

Comment: are you sure your **tuitFilePath[i]** has a value ?

Comment: i think it should, the txt file is populated.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution should work... for the last line that matches, and only that one.

LINQ can help you here, though. Here's a solution that should work.

```
tuitDisplayTextBox.Text = 
    File.ReadLines(Server.MapPath("~") +"/App_Data/tuitterMessages.txt")
        .Where(n => n.Contains(searchTextBox.Text)).Aggregate((a, b) =>
            a + Enviroment.NewLine + b);
```

Here, what it does is it reads the lines of the file into an `IEnumerable<string>`, and then I filter that with the `Where` method, which basically means "if the condition is true for this element, add this element to the list of things to return, else don't add it". And then `Aggregate` is a bit more complicated. Basically what it does is it takes the first two items from the collection, and then pass a lambda through them that returns a value. Then call the lambda again with that result and the third element. And then it takes **that** result and calls it with the fourth element. And so on.

Here's some code more similar to yours that will also work:

```
tuitDisplayTextBox.Text = "";
IEnumerable<string> lines = 
    File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~") +"/App_Data/tuitterMessages.txt");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    if (line.Contains(searchTextBox.Text))
    {
        sb.AppendLine(line);
    }
}
tuitDisplayTextBox.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Here it's a bit different. First it reads all the lines into an `IEnumerable<string>` called lines. Then it makes a `StringBuilder` object (basically a mutable `string`). After that, it foreaches the lines in the `IEnumerable<string>` (I thought it was more appropriate here) and then if the line contains the text you want, it adds that line and a newline to the `StringBuilder` object. After that, it sets your textbox's text to the result of all of that, by getting the `string` representation of the `StringBuilder` instance.

And if you **really** want a for loop, here's the code modified to use a for loop:

```
tuitDisplayTextBox.Text = "";
string[] lines =
    File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~") +"/App_Data/tuitterMessages.txt");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    if (lines[i].Contains(searchTextBox.Text))
    {
        sb.AppendLine(lines[i]);
    }
}
tuitDisplayTextBox.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Not really sure how this works, i want to use code similar to mine, but thanks!

Comment: @AnthonyJohnson Will add that, just a second.

Comment: @AnthonyJohnson Took slightly more than a second ;) , but it's here.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that File.ReadAllLines break sentences at '\r' or '\n'.
So, if you search for "hello world" and this text is break in the file into 2 lines (e.g. "... hello /n world" your code will failed...

So, use the ReadAllText() instead, return one string contains all file's text. 
Still, you might face sometimes problems with file encoding, but this is another issue.

After, and if, you find the text you are searching for you can use the ReadAllLines to decide about the location of the text.